# infinispan - locking in distributed cache with hot rod, is it possible?

Tags: locking, distributed-transactions, infinispan

I have to use distributed cache and I would like to use Infinispan 5.3 for that.
I examined the different connection modes and I picked hot rod to implement the client-server communication. I also need to lock a specific key in the cache and later after processing to unlock it (the places for locking and unlocking are in different class in my application...).

I read many documents, articles and forum entries regarding the issue but I haven't found any solution so far. If I interpreted properly what I read then it is not possible to lock the key manually in hot rod. I tried to handle the transactions manually but I am not sure how to do that. Perhaps it is not possible in Infinispan 5.3...?

Or can you tell me a different connection mode (instead of hot rod) that can provide me client-server communication and the locking is solved?

Thanks,
V.

Comment: I suppose transactions are supported only in embedded mode.

Comment: hmm, that is bad news... :( Thanks tsykora!

Comment: Do you really need to use client-server use case? What's your architecture? Just curious...

Comment: My application has to use more different types of cache implementation (ehcache, hazelcast, infinispan). I wanted to choose a communication mode for infinispan which is general enough. That was the reason why I thought of hotrod. And the cache server can be on different machine(s) too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remote transactions (and locking) via HotRod are not supported in Infinispan 5.3.

See [ISPN-375](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-375) and [ISPN-848](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-848).

Comment: Thanks Dan for the answer!